# Select every child element in HTML except one

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to edit the style of the HTML elements in my website using javascript but instead of having to write each child element except one, is there a method in javascript to select everything under the parent div `<div id = "pages">` except one child?

HTML

```
<div id = "pages">
  <div id = "page-1"></div>
  <div id = "page-2"></div>
  <div id = "page-3"></div>
  <div id = "page-4"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
//is there a way to select every pages in div id = "pages" except for one page without typing 
//everything manually?
document.getElementbyId("page-1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementbyId("page-2").style.display = "block";
document.getElementbyId("page-3").style.display = "none";
document.getElementbyId("page-4").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Instead of fighting the river, flow with the river: select all your elements, and select your one element. Then do `allOfThem.forEach(e => { if (e === thatOneElement) return doThatOneThing(e); doThatOtherThing(e); })`.

Comment: Which element you don't want to select?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is actually your task? Are you sure that a pure CSS is not enough for your task?

Comment: That right it can be solved through css. But his user use case might be different.

Comment: For example, when I visit page 1 I don't want page 2-4 to be visible and when I visit page 2 I don't want page 1,3,4 to be visible and so on

Answer (score 3):

this way:

```css
#pages > div:not([id="page-2"]) {
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<div id = "pages">
  <div id="page-1">page-1</div>
  <div id="page-2">page-2</div>
  <div id="page-3">page-3</div>
  <div id="page-4">page-4</div>
</div>
```

If you hate CSS:

```js
function ShowPage(pageID)
  {
  document.querySelectorAll('#pages > div').forEach(el =>
    {
    el.style.display = (el.id === pageID) ? 'block' : 'none'
    })
  }

ShowPage('page-2')
```

```html
<div id="pages">
  <div id="page-1">page-1</div>
  <div id="page-2">page-2</div>
  <div id="page-3">page-3</div>
  <div id="page-4">page-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Sometimes JS in not needed. Well, unless the elements need to swap dynamically on some *x* variable change...

Comment: I highly recommend the first solution, you'll be far happier with your code in the long term

Comment: yeah first one seems easier but I need to do it dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```js
let children = document.getElementById('pages').children;

for (let index = 0; index < children.length; index++){
  if (children[index].id !== 'page-2') {
    children[index].style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    children[index].style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id = "pages">
  <div id = "page-1">a</div>
  <div id = "page-2">b</div>
  <div id = "page-3">c</div>
  <div id = "page-4">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DatBoiTrump you're absolutely incorrect that `!=`  is the same as `!==`. Please learn the JS basics.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if you had read the message, I said, 'it doesn't make a difference'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to store your ids to not include, that way you can add more ids in the long run. Then loop through the divs and check if the id is in the array.

```js
const idsnotinclude = ["page-6"] 

 const divs = document.getElementById('pages').children;
 const divsArray = Array.from(divs);

 divsArray.forEach(function (div){
  if(idsnotinclude.includes(div.id)){
    div.style.display = "block";
    return;
  }
  
  div.style.display = "none";
 });
```

```html
<div id = "pages">
  <div id = "page-1">1</div>
  <div id = "page-2">2</div>
  <div id = "page-3">3</div>
  <div id = "page-4">4</div>
  <div id = "page-5">5</div>
  <div id = "page-6">6</div>
  <div id = "page-7">7</div>
  <div id = "page-8">8</div>
  <div id = "page-9">9</div>
  <div id = "page-10">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create a reusable function that accepts a desired page number
- Use the Attribute selector `[id^=page-]` (meaning: *starts with: `page-`*)
- Use a small regex to get the number suffix from every element ID
- Use Element.classList's `.toggle` method:

```js
const showPage = (num) => {
  document.querySelectorAll("[id^=page-]").forEach(EL => {
     const pageNum = +EL.id.replace(/\D+/, "");
     EL.classList.toggle("hide", pageNum !== num);
  });
};


showPage(2); 
showPage(3);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="pages">
  <div id="page-1">This is page 1</div>
  <div id="page-2">This is page 2</div>
  <div id="page-3">This is page 3</div>
  <div id="page-4">This is page 4</div>
</div>
```